Tomcat Session Statistics with Session ID
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/sessions?path=/examples
output:
OK - Session information for application at context path /examples
Default maximum session inactive interval 30 minutes
<1 minutes: 1 sessions
1 - <2 minutes: 1 sessions
but i want to get with session ID.
i tried this
http://localhost:8080/manager/text/sessions?path=/examples
output:
OK - Session information for application at context path /examples
Default maximum session inactive interval 30 minutes
<1 minutes: 1 sessions
1 - <2 minutes: 1 sessions

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
